# Do I still need to download something to use DataAnnotation with MVC 2.0 Preview 1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ScottGu says .NET MVC 2.0 has built in DataAnnotation support, I think that means I don't need to download the DataAnnotation DLLs separately, but when I installed MVC 2.0 and try to use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, my VWD prompts an error message:

Comment: Do you dare say that ScottGu is not telling the truth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should import or reference System.ComponentModel manually?

Answer (score 1):

You need .NET 3.5 sp1 installed.  Its not distributed with MVC 2.0.  I think what they're talking about is that System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll, which contains the DataAnnotations-compatible model binders, is being shipped whereas it wasn't with 1.0...

Comment: im 99% sure you need SP1 to run MVC at all - because of the routing infrastructure

Comment: Where are these DataAnnotations-compatible modelbinders?